# Eclipse not seeing test folder with Gradle plugin

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, gradle

I am using Gradle for my project, and the Eclipse plugin to generate Eclipse settings.

It successfully sees the main folder as a source folder, but not the test folder. This makes it a pain to automatically generate a unit test class through Eclipse.

How to fix this ?

Comment: @Reviewers, I am asking this question that way because there is no similarly-phrased question for this problem, even though the answer already exists for questions phrased a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your Gradle build file:

```
eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [configurations.testCompile]
```